# Javascript for a beginner, do I need it?

Tags: website, javascript, asp.net

I did a short course at Uni that gave me a taste of ASP.NET and I want to develop it further, so I'm teaching myself from a book.

Based on my studies; I only really know basic ASP.NET, decent-SQL, moderate-Java, moderate-Python and moderate HTML/CSS.

I want to be able to build some really cool interactive things on websites like slideshows and more; and I understand javascript is the best way to do this?

So my questions are:

1. Do I need javascript if I'm learning C# as part of ASP.NET?
2. If I do need it, what are the best resources to learn it for someone at my level? (Also, what's jQuery.. should I learn that too/instead of?).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You should learn Javascript if you are going to be at all involved with web development because it can be used, if done right, to:

- offload work from your web server to the client
- make the site appear much more responsive without incurring extra network activity back to the server

An example is using Javascript to validate values in a form before sending to the server.  You should still do this on the server (*always* validate everything coming from outside, *every time*), but doing it on the client as well will immediately notify the user if there's a problem without a need to send anything, and feels more responsive to the end user.

You can also do things like drop-down calendars to select date fields and such all on the client end without the server needing to generate them at all.

AJAX is also a core thing in making websites look and feel like desktop applications, and it's Javascript.

I have read bits and pieces about using Javascript on the server end for various tasks.  I'm not sure of the value in that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary but it could help you to make great and intuitive website.

Try course like [codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) or [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/) to learn javascript.

Jquery is a Javascript Library, it helps webmaster and developper to write less and do more in javascript. Really usefull and powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript if you're doing modern web development.

There is no way around it, it is the only thing browsers understand natively.